# Pandas Mapping Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 DATE        INTV        Y
2005-11-10 00:00:00.000 0
2005-11-10 00:30:00.000 0
2005-11-10 01:00:00.000 0
2005-11-10 01:30:00.000 1
2005-11-10 02:00:00.000 1
2005-11-10 02:30:00.000 0
...
2005-11-10 22:00:00.000 1
2005-11-10 22:30:00.000 3
2005-11-10 23:00:00.000 3
2005-11-10 23:30:00.000 0
```

i want to remap the INTV Column like this :

```
00:00:00.000 = 1
00:30:00.000 = 2
01:00:00.000 = 3
01:30:00.000 = 4
...
23:00:00.000 = 47
23:30:00.000 = 48
```

I tried with a dictionary and the .map function, but that didnt work as i want it.

Comment: Need `df['INTV'] = pd.factorize(df['INTV'])[1] + 1` I think

Comment: What is the dtype of the column INTV?

Comment: Make sure to check datatype of `INTV` and to match it with the one in your dictionary.

Comment: INTV has the dtype object

Comment: lots of ways to do this but best way might depend on why you want to do this?

Comment: @Henrij - I assume you want to find the "half-hour of the day" from a `datetime.time` object. Might we change the title to explain this better? Currently, it is very generic.

Comment: @JohnE its a part of the feature engineering for machine learning. The INTV is a feature. We have 48 Intervals per day. so i need to remap them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the INTV column is a `datetime` column then this is trivial,

```
df.INTV = df.INTV.dt.hour * 2 + df.INTV.dt.minute/30 + 1
```

Assuming it is a `datetime.time` column it becomes a little tricker as pandas `dt` does not support `datetime.time` objects,

```
df.INTV = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + df.INTV.astype(str)))
df.INTV = df.INTV.dt.hour * 2 + df.INTV.dt.minute/30 + 1
```

here, we just make a dummy `datetime` object from the `Date` and `INTV` column and then extract the hour and minutes as above.

Comment: intv column has the dtype object. how can i change it to time?

Comment: @Henrij - editing answer to include different dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary, for same format use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select first lists by `str[0]`:

```
d = dict(zip(pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-01-01 23:59:59', freq='30T')
               .strftime('%H:%M:%S'), range(1, 49)))

print (d)

{'00:30:00': 2, '13:30:00': 28, '07:00:00': 15, '19:30:00': 40, '12:00:00': 25, 
'10:30:00': 22, '01:30:00': 4, '14:30:00': 30, '21:00:00': 43, '11:00:00': 23, 
'16:00:00': 33, '06:30:00': 14, '05:00:00': 11, '03:00:00': 7, '20:00:00': 41, 
'06:00:00': 13, '01:00:00': 3, '18:00:00': 37, '15:00:00': 31, '09:00:00': 19, 
'19:00:00': 39, '02:30:00': 6, '23:00:00': 47, '02:00:00': 5, '08:30:00': 18, 
'14:00:00': 29, '17:00:00': 35, '13:00:00': 27, '21:30:00': 44, '04:30:00': 10, 
'07:30:00': 16, '18:30:00': 38, '16:30:00': 34, '23:30:00': 48, '00:00:00': 1, 
'17:30:00': 36, '05:30:00': 12, '10:00:00': 21, '11:30:00': 24, '15:30:00': 32, 
'22:00:00': 45, '20:30:00': 42, '04:00:00': 9, '09:30:00': 20, '03:30:00': 8, 
'08:00:00': 17, '12:30:00': 26, '22:30:00': 46}

df['new']=df['INTV'].str.split('.').str[0].map(d)
print (df)
         DATE          INTV  Y  new
0  2005-11-10  00:00:00.000  0    1
1  2005-11-10  00:30:00.000  0    2
2  2005-11-10  01:00:00.000  0    3
3  2005-11-10  01:30:00.000  1    4
4  2005-11-10  02:00:00.000  1    5
5  2005-11-10  02:30:00.000  0    6
6  2005-11-10  22:00:00.000  1   45
7  2005-11-10  22:30:00.000  3   46
8  2005-11-10  23:00:00.000  3   47
9  2005-11-10  23:30:00.000  0   48
```

Detail:

```
print (df['INTV'].str.split('.').str[0])
0    00:00:00
1    00:30:00
2    01:00:00
3    01:30:00
4    02:00:00
5    02:30:00
6    22:00:00
7    22:30:00
8    23:00:00
9    23:30:00
Name: INTV, dtype: object
```

Another, improved [josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789997/2901002) solution:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['INTV'])
df['new']= dates.dt.hour * 2 + dates.dt.minute//30 + 1
print (df)
         DATE          INTV  Y  new
0  2005-11-10  00:00:00.000  0    1
1  2005-11-10  00:30:00.000  0    2
2  2005-11-10  01:00:00.000  0    3
3  2005-11-10  01:30:00.000  1    4
4  2005-11-10  02:00:00.000  1    5
5  2005-11-10  02:30:00.000  0    6
6  2005-11-10  22:00:00.000  1   45
7  2005-11-10  22:30:00.000  3   46
8  2005-11-10  23:00:00.000  3   47
9  2005-11-10  23:30:00.000  0   48
```

Detail - date is not important, if parse only times is added today:

```
print (dates)
0   2017-10-17 00:00:00
1   2017-10-17 00:30:00
2   2017-10-17 01:00:00
3   2017-10-17 01:30:00
4   2017-10-17 02:00:00
5   2017-10-17 02:30:00
6   2017-10-17 22:00:00
7   2017-10-17 22:30:00
8   2017-10-17 23:00:00
9   2017-10-17 23:30:00
Name: INTV, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I think they want the half hour of the day.

Comment: date could be important if we have data that spans over summer times for given time zones.

Comment: @josh - I never see it before, can you explain more? In my opinion the best is the more general solution, if problem with timezones I think OP give comment. Or do you think is not good `dates = pd.to_datetime(df['INTV'])` ? If yes, why? Can you explain?

Comment: This is from experience working in energy markets. We use periods of HH in a day, normally 48, but 46 on the last Sunday of March and 50 in the last Sunday of Oct because of [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time). OP might not care but it is better to be safe than sorry, I think.

Comment: @josh - I not working in this are, so I was curiuous. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to you both :) josh solutions looks nice and works pretty well. i like smaller code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a "remap" function to make the changes you want and then apply it to the INTV series.

```
df['INTV']=df['INTV'].apply(remap_func)
```